# Hosting instruction videos for a paid app on youtube

Tags: licensing

Is it legal to host instruction videos for a paid app on youtube (for free)?

I'm working on a paid web app, and was thinking about uploading videos to youtube, unlisting them and embedding into my web app? Is this legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be allowed as long as you follow the terms of service of YouTube, and your app doesn't do illegal things.